# Sending notification sound with flutter firebase_messaging plugin

Tags: flutter, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get my application to send a notification to a user which will alert them with their default notification sound.

So far, I am using the plugin [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging) with the following code:

```
Message firebaseMessage = Message()
..to = token
..body = body
..title = title;
firebaseCloudMessage.send(firebaseMessage);
```

This allows me to send a notification to a selected user and display it on their home screen. The only problem is, it does not play a sound on iOS or give Apple Watch haptics when the notification is delivered.

How can I play a sound using the firebase_messaging framework?

If it helps, here is my configuration:

```
_firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
  IosNotificationSettings(
    sound: true,
    badge: true,
    alert: true
  )
);
```

Sounds and haptics work if I send a message directly from firebase and enable sounds in the options, I just can't work out how to do it with this framework.

Comment: How I am doing it directly from firebase is going to cloud messaging > compose notification > complete step 1 and 2. I then skip to stage 5 (Additional options) and enable sound from there. This is from the firebase console.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is too late.
But I have struggled with notification sound in iOS.
The problem was I was using Firebase to send the notification and it uses the latest API, so I had to add the "**apns**" part in the notification meassage:

```
     const payload = {
                      notification: {
                          title: "title",
                          body: "message",

                      },
                      data: {
                          info: "any data",
                          click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
                        },
                      apns:{
                        payload:{
                            aps:{
                             sound:"default"
                            }
                        }
                     },
                      condition:condition //if using topics
                 };
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the `fcm_push` package. You need to add an additional tag to your message. Try:

```
firebaseMessage.data = [Tuple2('sound', 'default')];
```

This works for Android. You may need to figure out how to get `fcm_push` to send the right payload for an APNS message. See the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#apnsconfig) and the [APNS payload reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1).

(I don't use `fcm_push` myself - I find it just as easy to write directly to the FCM API using HTTP. For example...)

```
final String url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

Map<String, dynamic> notification = {
  'body': 'some body',
  'title': 'some title',
};

Map<String, dynamic> data = {
  //'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
  'someKey': 'someValue',
  'sound': 'default',
};

Map<String, dynamic> message = {
  'notification': notification,
  'priority': 'high',
  'data': data,
  'to': '', // this is optional - used to send to one device
};

Map<String, String> headers = {
  'authorization': auth,
  'content-type': 'application/json',
};

void sendNotification() async {
  message['to'] = testToken; // todo - set the relevant values
  http.Response r =
      await http.post(url, headers: headers, body: json.encode(message));
  print(r.statusCode);
  print(r.body);
}
```

Comment: Where would I get my auth token? Also where does the body and title go?

Comment: You get the auth token from the Firebase console / Project Overview / Settings / Cloud Messaging page - look for the server key. See updated answer for body and title.

Comment: I was busy and forgot to reply. When sending manually, I didn't get any notification for iOS. I'm not testing Android as it's only a personal app so it can be iOS only.

Comment: In the original question you said you got a notification, but without sound. Were you able to add sound using the FCM API?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. What I mean is when I tried using the API manually like you do, I could not receive a notification at all. Could this maybe be because I need to register to receive the notifications differently?

Comment: No, no need to register differently. Before, were you using `fcm_psh` as well? Did you get notifications? Did adding the Tuple2 help?

Comment: Yes I was using `fcm_push` and no the Touple2 did not help with the sound. If I try making the request manually like you shown, I do not get any notification. Also I added the http package and had to remove `http.` from the code otherwise I had errors. Pressure you done something like import as.