# Flutter - disable incoming notification sound

Tags: flutter, push-notification

In my app users receive push notifications from other users of the app.

How can I let my users choose if they hear a sound when push notifications arrive.

Thanks,
Lior

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54039565/sending-notification-sound-with-flutter-firebase-messaging-plugin

Comment: Multumesc, Ciprian

Comment: Cu plăcere :) Did it help?

Answer (score 0):

Were you using any plugin to display notifications? If you're using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications), the notification sound can be disabled by setting the `playSound` to **false** for the [AndroidNotificationChannel](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/flutter_local_notifications/AndroidNotificationChannel-class.html), and `IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.requestPermissions(sound: false)` for [iOS](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/flutter_local_notifications/IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin-class.html).